# Mockery and Guzzle

Tags: php, symfony, guzzle, mockery

anyone test Guzzle with Mockery? When I try to create mock for guzzle client i get exception:

```
ErrorException: Runtime Notice: Declaration of Mockery_517a66dfe36b0::__call() should be compatible with Guzzle\Service\Client::__call($method, $args = NULL)
```

here is the code:

```
$mock = m::mock('\Guzzle\Service\Client');
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to create a mock of guzzle client, why not use the helper provided by guzzle:

```
$plugin = new Guzzle\Plugin\Mock\MockPlugin();
$plugin->addResponse(new Guzzle\Http\Message\Response(200));
$mockedClient = new Guzzle\Http\Client();
$mockedClient->addSubscriber($plugin);

// The following request will get the mock response from the plugin in FIFO order
$request = $client->get('http://www.test.com/');
$request->send();

// The MockPlugin maintains a list of requests that were mocked
$this->assertContainsOnly($request, $plugin->getReceivedRequests());
```

from [Unit Testing Guzzle clients](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing.html)

Comment: Because I don't work on clean client. I pass it to my mapper class with dependency injection. I try this solution but it's don't work for me.

Comment: I believe the link you have provided doesn't work any more. I've found these links on testing Guzzle clients: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/testing/unit-testing.html?highlight=unit%20testing and https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle-docs/blob/master/testing/unit-testing.rst#unit-testing-remote-apis

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:

```
$mock = m::mock('stdClass');
$mock->shouldReceive('addPerson')->once()->with(m::contains(1,1))->andReturn(array('id' => 1));

$response = new \Guzzle\Http\Message\Response(409);
$exception = new \Guzzle\Http\Exception\BadResponseException('error message', 409, null);
$exception->setResponse($response);
$mock->shouldReceive('addPerson')->once()->with(m::contains(1,2))->andThrow($exception);

$response = new \Guzzle\Http\Message\Response(404);
$exception = new \Guzzle\Http\Exception\BadResponseException('error message', 404, null);
$exception->setResponse($response);
$mock->shouldReceive('addPerson')->once()->with(m::contains(1,3))->andThrow($exception);

$mapper = $this->container->get('ftb.clubs.mapper');
$mapper->setClient($mock);

$id = $mapper->addPerson(1, 1);
$this->assertEquals(
    1,
    $id
);
```

Do You think that this has sense?

Answer (score 0):

Even if it's suggested by Guzzle itself, I prefer to have control on the client, and not relying on sequence of responses.

What if we can mock a response for each request? one to one?
That's why I developed this small composer library.

```
$ composer require doppiogancio/mocked-client
```

Whit this library you can mock the response for a specific url using:

1. A response object
2. A string response
3. A response content contained in a file

Just an example

```
$builder = new HandlerStackBuilder();


// Add a route with a response via callback
$builder->addRoute(
    'GET', '/country/IT', static function (ServerRequestInterface $request): Response {
        return new Response(200, [], '{"id":"+39","code":"IT","name":"Italy"}');
    }
);

// Add a route with a response in a text file
$builder->addRouteWithFile('GET',  '/country/IT/json', __DIR__ . '/fixtures/country.json');

// Add a route with a response in a string
$builder->addRouteWithFile('GET',  '{"id":"+39","code":"IT","name":"Italy"}');

// Add a route mocking directly the response
$builder->addRouteWithResponse('GET', '/admin/dashboard', new Response(401));

$client = new Client(['handler' => $builder->build()]);
```

Once you mocked the client, you can use it like this:

```
$response = $client->request('GET', '/country/DE/json');
$body = (string) $response->getBody();
$country = json_decode($body, true);

print_r($country);

// will return
Array
(
    [id] => +49
    [code] => DE
    [name] => Germany
)
```